# Stackoverflow for Mobile?

Tags: feature-request, support, mobile-web

I am great fan of Stackoverflow. I just can't stay without visiting it atleast a time in a day.Even in toilet , I used to browse some good questions on stackoverflow. But, It is very difficult to put comment or make the question favourite through mobile device. So I think there should be its mobile site for people like me. Is it available out there? Or can this feature be requested here ? Badly need some solution on it.

Comment: There is a mobile site. Look for the 'Mobile' link at the bottom.

Comment: Too much information.

Comment: Do you need a solution to this as badly as you need to go?

Comment: You have a stack of magazines gathering dust.

Comment: @andrew Failed to get your last comment..please explain?

Comment: Erm... a joke; many people read magazines on the toilet.

Comment: I was tempted to edit the question and leave only relevant part but then it would spoil all the fun.

Comment: There should be a badge for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the "mobile" link at the bottom of the page:

[image]

Then, the site will look somewhat like:

[image]

Comment: What's `Punch`?

Comment: @Pang: A userscript that I use: http://stackapps.com/q/3802/10098 . Since I took the second screenshot in a normal browser (just a resized window), all my userscripty goodness is still floating around :s

Comment: @Manishearth - And I tested punching on you! :)