# Python formatting on iPhone

Tags: bug, code-formatting

Python depends on formatting (new lines and indentation); it's part of the language.

However, the code markup in the editor messes with the formatting, sometimes incorrectly displaying multiline blocks.

Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

#### Update

OK, so it looks like this is only occurring on my phone. As an example, try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825910/django-subclassing-a-class-that-is-subclassing-an-abstract-base-class) on your phone (I'm on an iPhone).

Comment: Can you please include an example?

Comment: If you are copying and pasting code with tabs in it, the editor will mess that up yes. You should convert those tabs to use only spaces..

Comment: Note that the *majority* of python question askers manage to post code samples just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Don't tabs automatically get converted to 4 spaces?

Comment: @Asad The markdown source itself isn't changed and will continue to contain tabs, but the rendered version (both in the preview and in the version that eventually is rendered to the page) will have their tabs converted to align on four space-boundaries.

Comment: We really need an example of what you mean -- I don't understand what issue you're describing here.

Comment: @Asad: Things are complicated some more by the editor; if you paste tabs, the 'source code' button can actually remove initial tabs instead of add them. And if you *mix* tabs and spaces (4 space indents with 8-space tabs, etc) things get messy fast.

Comment: I'd be too busy demanding Python be fixed to come here.  Whitespace delimiters?  Eugh.

Comment: Just to check, you *did* review [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) right?

Comment: @Won't: You, me, outside. Let's have a 'discussion' about that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Somehow, I don't think that would be constructive..

Comment: @Won't: Just watch me go constructive on your *nose*! :-P

Comment: The discussion is likely to lead to a great deal of (facial) *re*-construction

Comment: @MartinPieters I guess that proves that the majority of posters aren't posting from the loo.

Comment: @Aidan Ewen: Please tell me that isn't in reference to [this question from earlier today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167221/stackoverflow-for-mobile).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Thanks for drawing my attention to it. Great question +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

It is not just python that has formatting messed up, although not all languages rely on whitespaces to convey actions.

Example with tabbing vs spaces: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1506555

that link was originally formatted with tabs, which was edited to display with spaces. With a language that relies on formatting to conver meaning, it could potentially change the coding commands.